# OpenGL ES2 shader error (I think)

Tags: android, opengl, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I am just beginner in gamedev, so when I finished testing my almost finished game on Linux PC, after that on Android Emulator, and game worked as I expected. But then I run my game on the Android Device, and I was impressed by blackness of screen, it was completely black.
After OpenGLES tracing, I think I found a place containing the error. Nevertheless, I do not know how to fix it.
The error is somewhere in the vertex shader, because it compiling time was 16ms(!) and then GLES gives an invalid pointer (-1) on the variables in the shader.

```
// VERTEX SHADER
uniform float aspectRatio;
uniform float size;
uniform vec2 translateVec;
attribute vec4 vertex;
mat4 projection = mat4(
    vec4(1.0/(aspectRatio*12), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec4(0.0, 1.0/12, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
);
mat4 translate = mat4(
    vec4(size, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec4(0.0, size, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec4(translateVec.x, translateVec.y, 0.0, 1.0)
);
void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * translate * vertex;
}

// FRAGMENT SHADER
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
    precision highp float;
#else
    precision mediump float;
#endif
uniform float color;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, color, color, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ERROR: ' * '  does not operate on 'float' and 'int'

#### ERROR: ' / ' does not operate on 'float' and 'int'

Replace

`(aspectRatio*12)`

to

```
(aspectRatio*12.0)
```

Replace

```
(1.0*12)
```

to

```
(1.0*12.0)
```